# Pandas- weekly histogram of timeseries data

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, histogram

I want to create a histogram of DateTime format data (with a 1-hour bin size). I can do it for one day like this in pandas:

df.set_index('timesheet_start', drop=False, inplace=True)
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='60Min')).count().plot(kind='bar')

However, I'd like to create a weekly histogram from Monday to Sunday for my data (1 histogram per week) which spans over 3 years. So in the example, 6/10/2107 (Monday) to 12/10/2017 (Sunday) > histogram 1
13/10/2017 (Monday) to 19/10/2017 (Sunday) > histogram 2
...
...

I really appreciate any help

Thank you in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what you mean by *"concatenating the data of 3 into one day and repead the above"*. Can you mabye make an example of input and desired output?

Anyway, pandas [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) function will may do what you want. It is IMHO way simpler as group-by for DateTime indexes and works like this:

```py
df.set_index('timesheet_start', inplace=True)
df_daily_sum = df.resample("1d").sum()
```

make sure you set a datetime as index

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've edited the question. I need a histogram with a 60min bin size not a count of timestamps per day. Any idea how I can do it?

Comment: Can you provide sample data? for what data do you want to make a hist? In our example above i can only see the timestamps, but not the actual data

Comment: Or in case you this is your data, say single time events and you want to make a hist when they occur, then 1. resample your data hourly `df.resample("1h").sum()` 2. plot a barplot for every week